# iOS Wikitude SDK (5.1.4) got crashed when lock the screen

Tags: ios, wikitude

In iOS SDK (5.1.4). Both the demo project and our app got crashed when I lock the screen and go back to the App.

The crash thread's back trace:

[image]

Another wikitude thread:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps a text-based stack trace would be more useful? Also, perhaps you could edit in the code that triggers this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the newly release Wikitude SDK 5.2.0 - it includes several stability improvements for pause/resume and power on/off cycles. Confident, that this will fix your issue.